# RPC connectivity issue

Tags: windows, rpc

I am experiencing a `RPC` connectivity issue.

I have two `RPC` servers built on `C++`.

- RPC Server 1: Windows 2000, IIS5, network 1
- RPC Server 2: Windows Server 2008, IIS7, network 1
- RPC Server 2 is more like an upgrade of RPC Server 1 machine

They both listen on the same port.

- Computer 1: Windows 7, network 2
- Computer 2: Windows XP, network 1
- Computer 3: Windows 7, network 1

I know that there are issues if any firewall is involved, this is not the case.

- Computer 1 --> RPC Server 1 not working (1722 The RPC server is unavailable)
- Computer 2 -->RPC Server 1 working
- Computer 1 --> RPC Server 2 working
- Computer 2 -->RPC Server 2 working
- Computer 3 --> RPC Server 1 not working (1722 The RPC server is unavailable)
- Computer 3 --> RPC Server 2 working

I used `rpcping` command to test connectivity.

What is strange is that I had a successfully connectivity `Computer 1 --> RPC Server 1` with a `VPN` connection, but only once (first attempt) and I couldn’t reproduce again, even if I deleted temporary internet files and flushed `DNS`.

Comment: What is _between_ the computers and the ancient server?

Comment: The same as between the computers and the new server.

Comment: You didn't describe that either! Exactly what does the network look like?

Comment: There is a firewall on network 1, but the connection can be established for other machines in network 1 or outside the network 1. So the firewall allows the connections. The only difference might be the OS, but since I succeeded that only once connection, the OS cannot be the problem. Can be any restrictions between OS versions and internet connectivity?

Comment: I end up by upgrading the RPC Server 1 to Windows Server 2008 and the problem was solved, but I still asking myself I there are some issues with RPC connection between different operating system versions.